# How to setTimeout only 1 time looping?

Tags: javascript

How to setTimeout only 1 time looping?

This code is looping forever and I just want it to loop only 1 time.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function doStuff() {
    document.myform.submit();
}
var myTimer = setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="" method="post">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use clearTimeout() method.

Comment: submitting the page reloads the page along with all of the javascript, which would re-register the `setTimeout`.

Comment: FYI, setTimeout _does_ only run once. The fact you're resubmitting the page puts it in an infinite loop.

Comment: That's because the form's action is blank, so it just does a post to the same page, over and over. What were you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Every time the form is submitted, the page is reloaded and `setTimeout` is called again.

You have to keep track of your page each time it's loaded. For example:

```
sessionStorage.submitted = new Date().toString();
```

And then check:

```
if (!sessionStorage.submitted)
    var myTimer = setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);
```

(Note: it doesn't work in IE7-.)

By the way, what's the point in submitting using POST to a static HTML page? Maybe there's some PHP code we're not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime your page posts and then loads, it calls the setTimeout again. Is this the functionality you want?

I think what you may want to do is:

```
var myTimer = function(){setTimeout(doStuff, 1000)};
```